# How to fix "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already executed." PID: 7664?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

This is my issue when I try to Login on Emulator!
[image]
[image]

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio, at least in my experience, has been extremely buggy. Try the following steps:

- Restart the emulator
- Wipe data from the device (using device manager)
- Use another emulator (create another device using device manager)
- Restart Android Studio
- Restart your PC

If none of the above work, create a new project and copy paste your code onto that project. I know it seems silly but it has actually worked for me!

Hope this helps.
-Suhas

Answer (score 0):

I remember having to deal with this error when I was working with Java web services, my problem was I didn't stop the service completely when I needed to reload it and when I tried to start a new instance it couldn't (giving me this error) because I had it already running. My "fix", for what I remember, was just going in the processes and stopping it manually.